# Oracle apex IG - single column not updating

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an IG in Oracle apex with several columns. One of the column doesn’t get saved/updated when user enters a value, while rest of the columns get updated fine.

Initially I suspected it to be an issue with page-region DML process, however I ruled out because all columns get updated fine.

Any thoughts on fixing this issue?

Comment: is your interactive grid created based on SQL Query? are you by any chance trying to update primary key column?

Comment: Yes it is based on sql and not updating a primary column

Comment: What is that column's **source** set to? Compare it to other columns!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... can you reproduce this behaviour at will ? In order for us to help you, please provide *as much info as possible*

Here are some things to check for the page/region/column:

- What is the source of the IG
- Is there any javascript that runs on "Execute when Page Loads" attribute (Page attributes)
- Is there any javascript defined in "Initialization JavaScript Function" (Interactive Grid Region > Attributes)
- Is there any javascript defined in "Initialization JavaScript Function" (Interactive Grid Region > Attributes)
- Is there any javascript defined in "Column Initialization JavaScript Function" (Interactive Grid Region > Column attributes
- What are the column attributes, what is the type, does the column have "Query only" or "Primary key" attributes checked.
- How is the interactive grid processed. Is this using type "Interactive Grid - Automatic Row Processing (DML) or do you have a custom pls/process. If custom, please provide
- Does the table have any triggers ?

If you can't get it to work when checking out the list of things above, please update your question with complete answers to all the questions.

Comment: and I'd try in a different browser, from a different network too